# How to configure git in netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans

What are the shortcuts to

1. commit ,
2. push ,
3. log,

How to get history in Netbeans Git?

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated by [issue 235887](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=235887), the general way to explorer shortcuts with NetBeans is:

```
Tools -> Options -> Keymap
```

The shortcut for commit, for instance, was added in [rev ca51cb132a44](http://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/rev/ca51cb132a44) in 2013.
You can attach a shortcut through `Tools -> Options -> Keymap -> Git/Commit Project...`

[Issue 257502](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257502) offers an example of key mapping:

> I used this mapping, although it conflicts with 'transpose letters' keys:
>
> - Push to upstream (git)  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
> - Pull from upstream (git)  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>
> - Commit project:           <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>

[Issue 232130](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232130) mentions selecting projects -> right click -> git -> show history (for `git log`).
But there is no graph visualization yet ([issue 221662](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221662))